# Finite-rank operators

Tags: operator-theory

If $K : X \to X$ is a Banach space and $F$ is a finite rank operator (so $R(F)$ is finite-dimensional), how can I show that $KF$ and $FK$ are finite-dimensional?

Comment: Does $R(F)$ refer to the image of $F$? By "show that $KF$ and $FK$ are finite-dimensional" do you wish to show that the images of $KF$ and $FK$ are finite-dimensional?

Comment: Yes to both statements.

Comment: $R(FK)\subset R(F)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $R(FK)\subset R(F)$ by definition. Indeed,
   $$
   R(F)=\{y\in X\colon \exists x\in X, y=Fx\}
   $$
   so for every $y\in R(FK)$ we have $y=F\underbrace{Kz}_{x}\in R(F)$.
2. $R(KF)=R(K|_{R(F)})=\text{span}(K(e_1),K(e_2),\ldots,K(e_n))$ where $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^n$ is a basis of $R(F)$.

Comment: Statement 1 seems to be the most helpful. But it is not obvious to me. Why is $R(FK) \subset R(F)$?

Comment: @user258647 Added more explanations to 1.